# How to automatically convert between remote and local file names?

Tags: tramp, find-file, remote, filenames

I have `/local/laptop/dir` mounted in my Docker container at `/container/path`.  In Emacs tramp terms, it is `/docker:container-id:/container/path`.  This also comes up when the user ssh to a remote system and the local system has via NFS or similar technology `/local/path` mounted to what tramp refers to as `/ssh:remotesys:/remote/path`.

In both cases, generally, I want to open the files via the local file name.  So, for example, in `eshell`, I could type `find-file golf` while on the remote system and Emacs would figure out the local file name if it existed.

I thought there was a way to automatically do this translation but I can't find any mention of it anywhere.

Comment: Does the question concern Eshell? It's not mentioned in the question. If not, please delete that tag. If yes, maybe say something about it in the question?

Comment: I suspect not. Tramp only need you remote or container path, there is fine without local path. I suggest you add a .dir-locals to save you local path and write some functions to hack find-file and other functions.

Comment: It is not specific to Eshell...  Sorry for the confusion.  Eshell is mentioned only as an example.

Comment: In Emacs terminology these are "file names", not "paths". A path is a list of directory/file names.

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [Remote Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Remote-Files.html).